# All Cdfs have a uniform distribution on [0, 1]?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Consider the following proposition

> Proposition C
>
> Let $Z = F(X)$; where $F$ is the continuous cumulative distribution function of the random variable X, then $Z$ has a uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$.
>
> **Proof**
>
> $$P(Z \leq z) = P(F(X) \leq z) = P(X \leq F^{-1}(z)) = F(F^{-1}(z)) = z$$
>
> This is the uniform cdf.

I can follow the proof above, but my interpretation of its meaning isn't making sense to me. This proof seems to imply that the cdf of any random variable has a uniform distribution. Is this correct? Is there an intuitive explanation for why this is?

For example, consider the graph of the cdf of some normal distributions from wikipedia

[image]

How would you map the ideas of this proposition to the graph of the cdf above?

Comment: You should specify that $F$ is the CdF of $X$, and not any function. Note that $X$ here is a random variable.

Comment: Sure, I've made the edits for clarity

Comment: Provided F is continuous.

Comment: Its doesn't mean that $F_X(x)$ is uniform but that $F_X(X)\sim U(0,1)$ if $F$ is continuous (on the other hand, $X\sim F^{-1}_X(U)$ holds for all $X$). The amount of time $X$ spends at $x$ is proportional to rate of growth of $F_X$ at $x$ which cancel out to make $F_X(X)$ uniform.

Comment: @A.S. I guess I can see how $F_X(X)$ is a uniformly distributed random variable because it's a probability. Can you provide a little more detail on your last sentence? I understand that how often $x$ occurs will be proportional to the cdf at that point, but exactly whats being canceled out? And how does that make it uniform? That's the part I'm still confused about

Comment: @Did I didn't know F needed to be continuous! But I'll update my question; I just copied the proposition from my textbook

Comment: Let $Y=F_X(X)$ and let $f_X=F'_X$. Then for $y\in (0,1)$, $f_Y(y)=f_X(y)\frac 1 {f_X(y)}=1$.

Comment: @A.S. Since $Y$ is a function of a random variable shouldn't the density be computed as follows? $f_Y(y) = f_X( F_X^{-1}(y)) \; \lvert \frac{d}{dy} F_X^{-1}(y) \rvert$

Comment: You are correct. The RHS of the last expression should have $F_X^{-1}(y)$ instead of $y$.

Comment: Alright, how did you determine that $\lvert \frac{d}{dy} F_X^{-1}(y)\rvert \equiv \frac{1}{f_X(F_X^{-1}(y))}$? That's currently not obvious to me, I could be missing something simple though.

Comment: Just added my own answer, I think it's correct, but I'm not sure. Any other comments would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is it the case that $P(F(X) \leq u) = P(F(X) < u)$? I have a proof where they equate these two, It is a proof for the exact same proposition but I cannot see why this is true. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

This proposition holds because of the way in which cumulative distribution functions are defined. First note that the proof involves the cdf of $Z = F(X)$, so in the proof we are looking at the cumulative distribution function **of** a cumulative distribution function.  For example, let $z = 0.4$ and consider the plot below

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

By definition, $P(Z \leq 0.4) = 0.4$, that is, the area under the cdf curve will be $0.4$ by  definition.

Also take note of the bounds, if $z < 0$ then $Z = 0$ while if $z > 1$ then $Z = 1$ so $Z$ has a uniform distribution only in [0, 1]

Comment: Is it the case that $P(F(X) \leq u) = P(F(X) < u)$? I have a proof where they equate these two, It is a proof for the exact same proposition but I cannot see why this is true. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Yeah I don't think my answer is correct. Would you mind posting your proof as an answer so I can take a look?