# Why does F(X) have uniform distribution in [0,1]?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable with strictly increasing $F(t)$ cumulative distribution function (with inverse function $F^{-1}(t)$). We can show that $F(X)$ ~ $unif(0,1)$:

$$P(F(X)≤t)=P(X≤F^{-1}(t))=F(F^{-1}(t))=t$$ for $0≤t≤1$
(plus a few more easy steps...)

Is there any intuitive explanation why $F(X)$ ~ $unif(0,1)$?

Related question, but unanswered: [All Cdfs have a uniform distribution on [0, 1]?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602205/all-cdfs-have-a-uniform-distribution-on-0-1)

Comment: The related question isn't unanswered; its asker just didn't select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $F$ is strictly increasing, it's invertible. Say $Y$ has another invertible cdf, $G$. Then $F^{-1}(X)$ and $G^{-1}(Y)$ have the same distribution. And if $Y$ happens to be uniformly distributed, $G$ is just the identity.