# Probability integral transformation for "continued" random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have stuck at the proof of the Probability Integral Transformation but for the continuation version of a discrete random variable.

By continuation version of a discrete random variable, I mean:

Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable with CDF $F_X$.
Set $Y = X + (U - 1)$ is the "continued" version of $X$, where $U$ and $X$ are independent, $U$ ~ Uniform[0;1].

It is claimed that the random variable $Z = F_Y(Y)$ is also Uniform[0;1]. I have tried to prove that but can't progress to the answer.

Could you please help me out with some sketch of the proof please ?

Thank you very much for your help!

--- UPDATE ---

It can be proved that $F_Y(y) = F_X([y]) + (y-[y]) . P(X = [y+1])$. The problem lies in how to prove $F_Y(y)$ is continuous.

Comment: You need to show $F_Y(Y)$ is continuous.  Then you can show $P(Z \le k)=k$ for $k \in (0,1)$ as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602205/all-cdfs-have-a-uniform-distribution-on-0-1 and various other questions here

Comment: @Henry: Hi, thank you very much for your help! The author gives me the form of $F_Y(y) = F_X( [y] ) + (y - [y]) . P(X = [y+1])$ where $[y]$ is the integer part of y. I have tried but still don't know to to arrive at the proof. If you have time, could you please give me further instruction please ? I'm stuck because I think that $F_X ([y])$ is not continuous as it is the cumulative distribution of the discrete random variable $X$. Thank you very much for your help, i'm very struggling.